# Robotframework getting array value from dictionary

Tags: python, testing, robotframework

I am having trouble retrieving a value from a dictionary in my robotframework test.

Right now I'm doing a query using the LDAP3 library that returns the following dictionary:

```
{'cn': ['Robotframework, U (User8072)'], 'dn': ['user=12345 OU=1,o=company,c=com '], 'uid': ['RobotframeworkU8072']}
```

What happens here is that the LDAP lib I'm using returns all the values as an array inside a dictionary item which means I can't get the value by using:

```
Dictionary Should Contain Item|${var}|uid|RobotframeworkU8072
```

Right now the only way I can get this to work is using the following which passes the test:

```
${test2}|Get From Dictionary|${test}|uid

${test3}|Get From List|${test2}|0

Should Be Equal|${test3}|RobotframeworkU8072
```

But is it really that complicated? Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use robot frameworks [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax):

```
should be equal  ${var['uid'][0]}  RobotframeworkU8072
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Cheers